# Restore a MOSS 2007 farm on a new server

Tags: sharepoint, backup, restore, administration

I'm currently trying to move a single-server farm to an other server. 
The old server is a windows 2003 32-bit with sql server 2005.
The new one is a windows 2008 32-bit with sql server 2008 r2 (32 bit).
Both MOSS 2007 have the same versions.

What I'm trying to do is to use a farm backup from the old server to restore it on the new one by using the restore tool on the central administration or by using the stsadm command, but it seems that it is not the best solution as the restore will fail.

In fact, what should I do on the new server ? Does it needs to exactly look like the old one ? Do I have to recreate all the web applications for instance ?

Is there any tutorial out there that could guide me step-by-step ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check technet> 
Back up and restore an entire farm (Office SharePoint Server 2007): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262412(v=office.12).aspx